# post arbitrary values from DOM (without form/submit i guess)

Tags: javascript, html

i want to create a button/input that when a user press it, it will call a java script function,

that collect some values from the DOM(using jQuery for example), can be different values, up to the user in page decisions, then post/submit all thoes values back to the server,

i know i can create a form with a button and create hidden input fields in the form and fill them when user make the needed decisions, but i got couple of thoes and i dont want do the same again and again...

im new to html/javascript and im sure there is more elegant way.. :)
thanks for all helpers!

jack

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com/)

Answer (score 1):

You can use Ajax for post or get (default). It's pretty straight-forward:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    data: {
         'put': 'your',
         'form': 'values',
         'here': '!'
    }
});
```

Comment: thats, combined with the previous answer is exacly what i looked for! :)   tnx Pumbaa80 and ruswick

Comment: Keep in mind that the browser won't redirect if you're doing an AJAX request. It runs in the background.

Answer (score 0):

A form is not a requisite to create a button. The `<button>` can be used to create a button arbitrarily.

jQuery can be used to execute a function using the `click()` method. For instance:

```
<button id="foo">Bar.</button>

<script>
    $('#foo').click(function(){
        someFunction();
    });
</script>
```

Here's a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/orzogen/Mgvr9/

Comment: ok, thanks, now i want that the function you wrote to collect some information from the DOM (for example collect some fields) and post them to the server, now whats the best way to do it?  create a form and fill it values then trigger the submit ?